# Shorthand way to refer to instance attributes in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python class that contains many variables, along the lines of:

```
class file:
    def __init__(self, name)
        self.name = name
        self.size = None
        self.num_lines = None
        self.directory = None
```

- Note that this is just an example - my real class has very descriptive (and therefore long) names and many more members

After I create an instance, I have to assign values to those variables:

```
f = file("abc.txt")
f.size = get_file_info(f.name)
f.num_lines = count_lines(f.name)
f.directory = get_dir(f.name)
f.new_name = root + f.directory + f.name + f.size
```

What I'd really like is the syntactic sugar of a ***using*** keyword:

```
f = file("abc.txt")
using f:
    size = get_file_info(name)
    num_lines = count_lines(name)
    directory = get_dir(name)
    new_name = root + directory + name + size
```

That is, I want to provide a new context in which variables will be searched for first, before Python does all the rest of its searches.

Is there anything like this? If not, it seems like a useful addition to the language.

Edit: Per the answers, I deliberately don't want to do this inside the **init** function. For personal reasons. Not really - it just doesn't make sense in my use case

Comment: Why aren't you doing that work inside `__init__`, instead of populating the attributes manually?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that, and I can't see it being accepted as a language change. As suggested above, you could just assign those attributes as part of initialising the instance.

Comment: Also note that `file` is a builtin type in Python 2.x. I wouldn't recommend defining your own class of that name.

Comment: @FredLarson Python 3 no longer has a built-in `file` type, but at least following the convention of CamelCase class names would be a good idea.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks. I modified my comment.

Comment: Other languages have, in the past, had such a feature (I'm thinking specifically of the `with` construct in Pascal). It's typically considered a bad idea, as it makes it less clear which names are attributes/members/etc of another object, and which are actually local variables.

Comment: And if you dont want them to be executed in the initialization, make one or multiple extra methods that do this for you so that you will only need to write `f.count_lines()` and it gets the name from `self`

Comment: These are instance variables, not class variables.

Comment: There is no shorthand way, and I believe that is a good thing.

Comment: @chepner: re Pascal's with: Python is already replete with confusion when it comes to what variables an identifier refers to. That is probably the biggest learning curve for the language. My proposal is just adding an *explicit* new layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support in the language for this. You can only create variable namespaces by functions and modules. Not even with classes (that's why, even inside a class, you have to use `self` to refer to its attributes)

Answer (score 0):

All the code you want to put in a `using` block should be handled by your class's `__init__` method.

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, name)
        self.name = name
        self.size = get_file_info(name)
        self.num_lines = count_lines(name)
        self.directory = get_dir(name)
        self.new_name = os.path.join(root, self.directory, self.name, self.fize)

f = File("abc.txt")
```

Some of the functions you imply (`get_file_info`, etc.) may be more suited to being methods of the `File` class, rather than standalone functions that take a file name as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! This was just example code to make my point - my real code is not related to file processing, and the functionality needed to set the additional values not already assigned in __init__ are not transportable to it. I apologize for not making it clearer in my original post that I was not trying to re-invent the file type!